# Jetty Acceptor threads Blocked

Tags: multithreading, websocket, jetty, server

I am running jetty-distribution-9.2.7 on our staging server and I see the following in the thread dump. Does not look very normal.

```
 48 qtp1275220739-48-acceptor-11@4b9666cf-ServerConnector@65a31764{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:80} BLOCKED
 |   |   +- sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:225)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.accept(ServerConnector.java:377)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:500)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
 |   |   +- java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Running the same jetty version of production server and getting similar situation (blocked threads). The difference is the Thread blocks I see in staging are with acceptor threads and with the production server, it is with our own code. I checked all the possibilities deadlocks within our code flow but could not find one.  Any suggestions?

```
- 253 qtp364089744-253 BLOCKED
 |   |   +- com.acti.chat.chatsession.SBChatEngine.sendChatToAvailableAgent(SBChatEngine.java:174)
 |   |   +- com.acti.chat.chatsession.ConnectionInitializer.connectActResReq(ConnectionInitializer.java:549)
 |   |   +- com.acti.common.util.ETTServiceUtil.submitInteraction(ETTServiceUtil.java:1540)
 |   |   +- com.acti.common.util.ETTServiceUtil.setArBeanToCache(ETTServiceUtil.java:595)
 |   |   +- org.xmpp.controller.CacheManagerController.routeActiveResponseToAgents(CacheManagerController.java:197)
 |   |   +- sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)
 |   |   +- sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 |   |   +- java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 |   |   +- org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
 |   |   +- org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
 |   |   +- org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
 |   |   +- org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:774)
 |   |   +- org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
 |   |   +- org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
 |   |   +- org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
 |   |   +- javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
 |   |   +- javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:224)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:245)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
 |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
 |   |   +- java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: 2 things. first (and most importantly) [Jetty 9.2.7 has a critical vulnerability](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00075.html), you should upgrade.  with that out of the way ... this seems similar to a JVM bug seen in the past, what version of Java are you running, and on what platform/os/version?

Comment: I am testing 9.2.9 on our staging.
I thought it was something to do with JDK. We were on OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) and now I moved to Oracle java build 1.7.0_75-b13. That did not make any difference.  Still trying.

Comment: OS: ubuntu 14.04 trusty

The server is running on m3.large amazon instance. ( 7.5 GB RAM and 2 CPUS, High Frequency Intel Xeon E5-2670 v2 (Ivy Bridge) Processors* SSD-based instance storage for fast I/O performance Balance of compute, memory, and network resources )

Comment: On 9.2.9 on production! Still the same issue :(

Comment: Hi Valli, did you find out anything about this issue in the meantime? We might be having a similar issue.

Comment: Hi Thomas Kappler. Yes. We resolved the problem. The problem was internal dead locks. The code had some Synchronized blocks that was causing the request pool to exhaust. That was the issue in my case. Please post your problem details as well. It would be interesting to know the pattern.